# WebSocket in Dart doesn't return echo messages

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I'm trying to make simple echo WebSocket in Dart with remote server, but it's not work (I don't get echo messages back to me). There is no compile errors or logs. No issues with Flutter Doctor. Rebuild doesn't help.
I could find only outdated examples for localhost and not for server.
Both machines are on the same network and can see each other.

server app code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8082);
  server.transform(WebSocketTransformer()).listen(onWebSocketData);
}

void onWebSocketData(WebSocket client){
  client.listen((data) {
    client.add('Echo: $data');
  });
}
```

echo app code:

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('wss://172.22.185.10:8082'),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : '');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
      ), 
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel.sink.close();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I was not able to find any detailed documentation or up-to-date answers, so...
Please help me if you can <3

Comment: The question can be boiled down to this statement `but it's not work`. Consider on elaborating on what exactly is not working and how.

Comment: @Boaz i didn't get echo messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For server shelf package used

`shelf_web_socket: ^1.0.1`
Client is mentioned in flutter documentation

**Client.dart**

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://localhost:9001'),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : '');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel.sink.close();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Server.dart**

```
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as shelf_io;
import 'package:shelf_web_socket/shelf_web_socket.dart';

void main() {
  var handler = webSocketHandler((webSocket) {
    webSocket.stream.listen((message) {
      webSocket.sink.add("echo $message");
    });
  });


  shelf_io.serve(handler, 'localhost', 9001).then((server) {
    print('Serving at ws://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
  });
}
```

### **Remote Accessing**

Remote accessing not a complicated
in your server side has a firewall . so you need to allow connection to this port( here 9001) for outside acces.Set your server ip in the code instead of localhost in both side like client and server.

[image]

**Allow port in firewall on windows Os**

**1**

[image]

**2**

[image]

**3**

[image]

**4**

[image]

**5**

[image]

**6**

[image]

**7**

[image]

Done.now you can access the port outside.

Comment: It's work fine on localhost, but i need to connect to remote server in local network (2 different machines)

Comment: @Kirsch updated my answer with remote access.please check